# PHP - Showing Database values in a form by selecting ComboBox value

Tags: php, mysqli

I am working on a project. Facing a problem on accessing database values.
this is my code of combobox  :

```
<select name="pp">
    <option>--Title--</option>
    <?php include('DBConnect.php');
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from table");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){?>
    <option><?php echo $row['Teach_PPIJ_TNO']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

(ComboBOx values are fetched by `mysql` query and its working)

And I have a form, fields are equals to table fields

And form also contains Show(submit) button.

Problem : How can I show Database values in that form's fields by selecting combobox values and clicking on show button.

**EDITED :** Check this screenshot for better understanding

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w0glc7mhwtnc75q/Untitled.jpg

In this image, Combobox shows only one column of the table ('Titles with page numbers' clumn), and after selecting combobox values, should display its corresponding row's values in above form. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but if I do I think AJAX is what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit better? I don't I fully understand it.

Comment: Combobox values shows only one column of the database. and  When selecting the particular values in combox, then its corresponding row's values should be visible in a form.

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by combobox. And you doesn't require ajax if it doesn't mean that page would be refreshed after click on show.

Comment: I asked this question 4 years ago. I was noob back then. This question is not relevant to me now. I can handle above problem since I have experience.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your problem correcly, you want to change form field values accordingly to selected value. This can be achieved in ways using javascript or refreshing page and loading using PHP.

Method using Javascript(jQuery)

```
<select name="pp" onchange="handleDroplistChange(this);"> 
    <option>--Title--</option> 
    <?php 
    include('DBConnect.php'); 
    $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * from table", $con); 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
    ?>
    <option><?php echo $row['Teach_PPIJ_TNO']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>

<!-- other input to load after selecting value-->
<input id= "field1" type="text" name="field_name">
<script>
    function handleDroplistChange(droplist)
    {
        var request = jQuery.ajax('somescript.php?selected_value='+droplist.value);
        request.done(function(data){
            var result = JSON.decode(data);
            jq('#field1').val(result.field_name); // assuming that returning object with field names as attributes
        });
    }
</script>
```

Method using refreshing

```
<select name="pp" onchange="window.location='somescript.php?selected_value='+this.value"> 
    <option>--Title--</option> 
    <?php 
    include('DBConnect.php'); 
    $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * from table", $con); 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
    ?>
    <option><?php echo $row['Teach_PPIJ_TNO']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>

<!-- other input to load after selecting value-->
<?php
// load values according to selected value
$selected_value = $_GET['selected_value'];
?>

<input id= "field1" type="text" name="field_name" value="<?php echo $retrieved_value;?>">
```

Comment: Sorry for vague writing. And thanx for you reply. I dont know much about ajax, but I can understand what you are suggesting. But Combobox shows only one column of the database.. So selecting particular value of combobox, should Display That value's corresponding row in a form on the same page.

Comment: So why do you need combobox if there is only one value? if there can be more second method(from answer) should work

Comment: Not one value... All the values from one columnm Check image i updated... But thank you for helping me and for replying. I got the solution. Before I was processing form through separate php file . but to achieve my goal I will have to write script on the same file where form exits. I know its quite confusing for you. But My problem has been solved. Thanks for reply :)